# Como descobrir possíveis Exceptions?

Tags: flutter, dart

Exemplo, em requisições http podemos ter `SocketException`, `TimeoutException`,etc

Em operações de I/O também temos outras possíveis `Exceptions`.

Para não ter que tratar de forma genérica, ex: `catch (e)`, como descobrir (documentação, etc) quais são as possíveis Exceptions que podem ocorrer tomando como exemplo os casos citados acima?

Comment: Em resumo para todas linguagens: leia a documentação.

Comment: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/dart_programming/dart_programming_exceptions.htm 

Comment: Isso não é documentação, é um texto ruim sobre o assunto. Documentação é da API, cada uma tem a sua.

Comment: A documentação oficial também não ajuda muito (https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.8.4/dart-core/Exception-class.html) 
Ou eu não saiba como localizar.

Comment: Ajuda, tem que olhar de cada API, não adianta olhar a classe `Exception`, mesmo erro da resposta aceita e do AP na duplicata do PHP que adicionei. Não tem lista, é impossível ter.